# Transform a dataframe with several dummies

Tags: r, database, dataframe, transform

I would like to transform the following dataframe:

[image]

into:

[image]

For each value (qualitative) of the variables presented in a column (initial table), I'd like to create a variable that takes the value 0 or 1 if the variable applies.

The screenshot was taken using Excel so that I could show the desired end result, but otherwise, I work with R. I don't know how to do it or what it's called. Could you please help me?

Comment: What you are trying to do is sometimes called "one hot encoding"